# Apache listener ports not working form outside

Tags: windows, apache, listener

I'm trying to add some listeners to my localhost at my Win8 Pro PC so I can enter different vHosts with my smartphone or my tablet. Need for example to test my responsive designs etc.

For exampla I got this in my http-vhosts.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:/XAMPP/xampp/htdocs/path/to/project"
    ServerName sprout.x
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    <Directory "G:/XAMPP/xampp/htdocs/path/to/project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:5000>
    DocumentRoot "G:/XAMPP/xampp/htdocs/path/to/project"
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's what I have in my httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 5000
```

When I enter it from my desktop PC, I can reach it using: `http://localhost:5000/`

When I try to enter it from another device like my tablet - which is in the same network - I always get to the localhost of my desktop PC: `http://192.168.2.124:5000`

Hope I did explain it so anyone does understand what I mean. As you can see my only problem is that the listening on port 5000 (for example) does not work from outside. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advice for any help!!!

Comment: You need to do port fowarding configuration on your router for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

99% likely this is just Windows Firewall.

Open up the Firewall settings from the Windows Control Panel.  Click "Allow and app or feature through Windows Firewall".  Then click "Change Settings" followed by the "Allow another app..." button.  Select the Apache.exe binary.

Alternatively, you cans select "Advanced Settings" from the first Firewall control panel screen, right click on "Inbound Rules", and select "New Rule". Then go through the wizard to allow Apache (or just enabled port 80 and 5000).

And that should do it.

Comment: Hi Selbie!Many thanks for your help. Unfortunately it doesn't work. The httpd.exe had have all the rights, ports are set... still it hits the root when connected from outside :(